# How to download python linter in vscode with this error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

its a very dummy question but i couldn't figure it out. When i try to download  a linter from vscode the problem shows up

> C:\Users\burak kaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\burak': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

The problem occurred due to the whitespace in my folder(Which is automatically created by Windows and i couldn't change it)
I tried to change my user name and the folder name is still same and need to download the linter.

I download linter with pip but vscode don't see that. It still asking to install a linter to me.

Answer (score 0):

So you can't just change the name of the folder and call it a day. Changing the username and folder on Windows is a bit more involved and requires you to modify the registry. Here's a quick video that gives instructions. I've done this twice.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5N2aaiToiQ

At the beginning, when he says you need to create a local user account, you don't need to do that. The user is already created which, for you, appears to be burak kaya.